# Creating a sequence in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to create a list containing all the numbers between `a` and `b` by every `60` without using loops?  Assume that `a` and `b` are separated by more than 60.

Answer (score 2):

You need [range()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#range) function. In case of python2:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1260
>>> range(a, b, 60)
[1, 61, 121, 181, 241, 301, 361, 421, 481, 541, 601, 661, 721, 781, 841, 901, 961, 1021, 1081, 1141, 1201]
```

In case of python3 you need to make a list from it:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1260
>>> range(a, b, 60)
range(1, 1260, 60)
>>> list(range(a, b, 60))
[1, 61, 121, 181, 241, 301, 361, 421, 481, 541, 601, 661, 721, 781, 841, 901, 961, 1021, 1081, 1141, 1201]
```